# Testing a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: testing, jupyter-notebook, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to come up with a method to test a number of Jupyter notebooks. A test should run when a new notebook is implemented in a Github branch and submitted for a pull request. The tests are not that complicated, they are mostly just testing if the notebook runs end-to-end and without any errors, and maybe a few asserts. However:

- There are certain calls in some cells that need to be mocked, e.g. a call to download the data from a database.
- There may be some magic cells in the notebooks which run a pip command or something else.

I am open to use any testing library, such as 'pytest' or `unittest`, although `pytest` is preferred.

I looked at a few libraries for testing notebooks such as [nbmake](https://github.com/treebeardtech/nbmake), [treon](https://github.com/ReviewNB/treon), and [testbook](https://github.com/nteract/testbook), but I was unable to make them work. I also tried to convert the notebook to a python file, but the magic cells were converted to a `get_ipython().run_cell_magic(...)` call which became an issue, since `pytest` uses python and not ipython, and `get_ipython()` is only available in ipython.

So, I am wondering what is a good way to test jupyter notebooks with all of that in mind. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my own solution using [testbook](https://github.com/nteract/testbook).  Let's say I have a notebook called `my_notebook.ipynb` with the following content:

[image]

The trick is to inject a cell before my call to `bigquery.Client` and mock it:

```py
from testbook import testbook

@testbook('./my_notebook.ipynb')
def test_get_details(tb):
    tb.inject(
        """
        import mock
        mock_client = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_df = pd.DataFrame()
        mock_df['week'] = range(10)
        mock_df['count'] = 5
        p1 = mock.patch.object(bigquery, 'Client', return_value=mock_client)
        mock_client.query().result().to_dataframe.return_value = mock_df
        p1.start()
        """,
        before=2,
        run=False
    )
    tb.execute()
    dataframe = tb.get('dataframe')
    assert dataframe.shape == (10, 2)

    x = tb.get('x')
    assert x == 7
```

Comment: This is excellent!!

Answer (score 3):

One straightforward approach I've already used is to execute the entire notebook with [`nbconvert`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

A notebook `failed.ipynb` raising an exception will result in a failed run thanks to the `--execute` option that tells `nbconvert` to execute the notebook prior to its conversion.

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute failed.ipynb
# ...
# Exception: FAILED
echo $?
# 1
```

Another correct notebook `passed.ipynb` will result in a successful export.

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute passed.ipynb
# [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook passed.ipynb to notebook
# [NbConvertApp] Writing 1172 bytes to passed.nbconvert.ipynb
echo $?
# 0
```

Cherry on the cake, you can do the same [through the API](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html#Using-nbconvert-as-a-library) and so wrap it in Pytest!

```py
import nbformat
import pytest
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

@pytest.mark.parametrize("notebook", ["passed.ipynb", "failed.ipynb"])
def test_notebook_exec(notebook):
  with open(notebook) as f:
      nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
      ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
      try:
        assert ep.preprocess(nb) is not None, f"Got empty notebook for {notebook}"
      except Exception:
          assert False, f"Failed executing {notebook}"
```

Running the test gives.

```sh
pytest test_nbconv.py
# FAILED test_nbconv.py::test_notebook_exec[failed.ipynb] - AssertionError: Failed executing failed.ipynb
# PASSED test_nbconv.py::test_notebook_exec[passed.ipynb]
```

#### Notes

- There is several [output formats](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#supported-output-formats), I've used here `notebook`.

> This doesn’t convert a notebook to a different format per se, instead it allows the running of nbconvert preprocessors on a notebook, and/or conversion to other notebook formats.

- The python code example is just a quick draft it can be largely improved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain how you mock an object used in the notebook in this method (e.g. BigQuery Client)? Also, how do you deal with a magic cell (e.g. "!pip install pandas") ?

Comment: @shahins magic will be executed -- you can check what is going on by using the `--debug` flag. For the mock part I don't know. Mocking is a complex topic if you want to ensure that interfaces for all cells are available. Maybe it should be a rule in each notebook to provide a "mock" mode--a way of executing it without everything plugged. Without this it will be a hell to try to mock everything from the outside.

Comment: Nice, I think this solution works well as long as you don't need to mock objects. In my case however, that is a major requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `nbval` (at https://nbval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or https://github.com/computationalmodelling/nbval for the source. It is an extension to `pytest`.

The basic idea is to execute the notebook and compare the computed output with output saved in the notebook file. Each cell is regarded as a test: if the cell's re-computed output matches that on disk, the test is considered to pass. (Otherwise a fail.)

The tests can be run using, for example:

```
$ py.test --nbval my_notebook.ipynb
```

In `lax` mode, the ouput of a cell is ignored, and the notebook passes as long as no exception are raised. This is a convenient way to check if any interface changes have broken the notebook (good to test notebook-based documentation):

```
$ py.test --nbval-lax my_notebook.ipynb
```

It is possible to skip particular cells, or ignore the output they produce, or expect exceptions to be raised. It is also possible to define (regexp) exceptions to---in effect---ignore output changes that are expected to differ in repeated executions (such as memory addresses, execution date and time, or run time).

I don't think mocking is possible.

The package is available on PyPI (https://pypi.org/project/nbval/).

A video on the nbval package (from Thomas Kluyver at the EuroSciPy 2017) is available at https://youtu.be/o-6nuopYIcs?si=NACh-NZaBkx4CZWq .