# Reset previous run for Unit tests for functions in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, unit-testing, jupyter-notebook, python-unittest

I have the following simple function in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

and then I do some UnitTest as follows in same notebook below:

```
import unittest

class TestNotebook(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(add(2, 2), 4)
        

unittest.main(argv=[''], verbosity=2, exit=False)
```

I get the following output:

```
test_add (__main__.TestNotebook.test_add) ... ok
test_drop_duplicates (__main__.TestSilver.test_drop_duplicates) ... ERROR
test_make_url_v1 (__main__.TestUrl.test_make_url_v1) ... ERROR
test_make_url_v2 (__main__.TestUrl.test_make_url_v2) ... ok
ERROR: test_make_url_v1 (__main__.TestUrl.test_make_url_v1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1252/4074376083.py", line 9, in test_make_url_v1
    date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 311)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: day is out of range for month

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.130s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

The question is: As you can see, I only executed one test which was **test_add** but in the output, I can still see some old (work-in-progress) tests that I ran like an hour ago? How do I clear the log or memory so only current test that is ran is printed in logs?

Comment: Have you restarted the kernel since earlier? Running, active `.ipynb` notebooks have a persistent namespace, just like running an IPython session on the command line. Example: if in the first cell of your notebook you ran `a = 5` and then later deleted that cell, or replaced the contents with unrelated code & ran that, and ran a lot of other cells, as long as you didn't re-assign `a` as anything else then `a` is still `5`. (You can see it listed in there if you run `globals()` in a cell.) However, if you restart the kernel it will be gone. You should be in a habit of restarting frequently.

Comment: If you are looking to test code in notebooks, some other resources are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405555/8508004) and here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77674184/8508004). You'll want to check out some of the other answers in the thread besides the ones I directly linked.

Comment: @Wayne - Thank you. Yes it worked when i restart kernel. I thought it could be done another way but it works.

Comment: You can probably clear it another way and maybe unittest offers an option; however, in this case you are already using a Jupyter notebook file, and so you might as well get used to restarting the kernel regularly and running all the cells, or at least all the cells above where you are if you have a few towards the end in the works. That gets rid of the hidden state being a problem or at least lets you know sooner that you have hit a hidden state issue when you are more likely to remember what was going on.